# Create/generate image URL from base64 string

Tags: ios, image, google-app-engine, web-applications, imageurl

I have a mobile based application that uses `REST` based service to upload images. The images are stored/retrieved in database as blob. Clearly so, now we have space and performance overheads, which is not working.

What needs to be implemented now, is a file system for image hosting. My web application is hosted on `Google app engine`, creating a file system and storing the files url in database, would require me to purchase extra storage space.

I have heard about `free` image hosting services online? Having never used any of them before, I need to know about any popular/reliable image sharing services online? Also, the ones that expose their services to my web application, and return a generated url in response. Which would ofcourse be stored in my database, in place of the `string`. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not a development question, at least not fully.

I suggest checking out free Tier AWS, or just ponying up a few bucks a month for hosting at Digital Ocean or something like that.

Also, if you store them as a url, you can use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];
```

Comment: GAE does not has a support for AWS for the obvious reasons whatsoever. As it does not allow apache http client, multithreads and open sockets to be accessed within the engine itself. There are a few hacks and workarounds, but storing the images as blob in datastore would do it for me..